# How i can close ChildWindow in silverlight from page?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight-4.0, childwindow

I have page.xaml and childwindow. How i can close the childwindow from page.xaml. Example by click on button in page.xaml. How i can get this childWindow from code?

Comment: You should accept some answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your ChildWindow example x:Name="myChildWindow" under your page.xaml button click event in your code behind put this

```
myChildWindow.Close();
```

Comment: myChildWindow - local variable. Do you have any idea? I fix this issue. I declare this variable global, and siple myChildWindow.Close(). But if local variable i use FindName(), and no result.

Comment: can you pls post your code or a link to where I can download it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a Close method on the ChildWindow object.  By calling this method, the window will close.

[See the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow.close%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: First, i must find open childWindow, then close. I can't find him. If myChildWindow - global variable, all is just.

Comment: Then simply make myChildWindow a global variable on the page by providing an x:Name to the ChildWindow element.

Is there a reason why you dont want to make it a global variable?